# why is re.findall regex matching only one group?

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to build a regex to parse some HTTP requests e.g.

```
146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622
197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554
156.127.178.177 - okuneva5222 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700] "DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1" 416 14701
100.32.205.59 - ortiz8891 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:28 -0700] "PATCH /architectures HTTP/1.0" 204 6048
168.95.156.240 - stark2413 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:31 -0700] "GET /engage HTTP/2.0" 201 9645
71.172.239.195 - dooley1853 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:32 -0700] "PUT /cutting-edge HTTP/2.0" 406 24498
180.95.121.94 - mohr6893 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:34 -0700] "PATCH /extensible/reinvent HTTP/1.1" 201 27330
144.23.247.108 - auer7552 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:35 -0700] "POST /extensible/infrastructures/one-to-one/enterprise HTTP/1.1" 100 22921
2.179.103.97 - lind8584 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:36 -0700] "POST /grow/front-end/e-commerce/robust HTTP/2.0" 304 14641
241.114.184.133 - tromp8355 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:37 -0700] "GET /redefine/orchestrate HTTP/1.0" 204 29059
224.188.38.4 - keebler1423 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:40 -0700] "PUT /orchestrate/out-of-the-box/unleash/syndicate HTTP/1.1" 404 28211
94.11.36.112 - klein8508 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:41 -0700] "POST /enhance/solutions/bricks-and-clicks HTTP/1.1" 404 24768
126.196.238.197 - gusikowski9864 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:45 -0700] "DELETE /rich/reinvent HTTP/2.0" 405 7894
103.247.168.212 - medhurst2732 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:49 -0700] "HEAD /scale/global/leverage HTTP/1.0" 203 15844
57.86.153.68 - dubuque8645 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:50 -0700] "POST /innovative/roi/robust/systems HTTP/1.1" 406 29046
231.220.8.214 - luettgen1860 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:52 -0700] "HEAD /systems/sexy HTTP/1.1" 201 2578
219.133.7.154 - price5585 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:53 -0700] "GET /incubate/incubate HTTP/1.1" 201 12126
159.252.184.44 - fay7852 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:54 -0700] "GET /convergence HTTP/2.0" 404 23856
40.167.172.66 - kshlerin3090 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:57 -0700] "HEAD /convergence HTTP/2.0" 501 16287
167.153.239.72 - schaden8853 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:58 -0700] "DELETE /bandwidth/reintermediate/engage HTTP/2.0" 302 17774
```

my current regex is:

```py
    return re.findall(
        r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s*\-"                             # match host name and following '-'
        r"\s*[\-\w]+\s"                                                        # match username or '-' (missing username)
        r"\[\d{1,2}/[A-Z][a-z]{2}/\d{4}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s-\d{4}\]\s"   # match request time
        r"\"(CONNECT|DELETE|GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|PATCH|POST|PUT|TRACE)\s*"         # match HTTP request type
        r"/[A-Za-z0-9\-\:/\?#\[\]\@\!\$\'\(\)\*\+\,\;\%\=]*\s*"                # match url
        r"HTTP/\d\.\d"                                                         # match http version
        , log_data
    )
```

if you would like to stick it into something like regex 101 here is the same regex in one string:

```
\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s*\-\s*[\-\w]+\s\[\d{1,2}/[A-Z][a-z]{2}/\d{4}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s-\d{4}\]\s\"(CONNECT|DELETE|GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|PATCH|POST|PUT|TRACE)\s*/[A-Za-z0-9\-\:/\?#\[\]\@\!\$\'\(\)\*\+\,\;\%\=]*\s*HTTP/\d\.\d
```

Based on the the fact I have a 979 line log and am getting 979 matches, as well as tests of smaller sections of the regex I'm confident I'm matching correctly, however, the regex only returns the HTTP request type e.g. 'HEAD' 'GET' or 'DELETE' whereas I'm wanting the host, username, time and full request e.g.

```
146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1
```

could you please let me know how to modify the regex to do this,
Thanks,

Comment: You only have one capturing group in your regex, so [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) is only returning the contents of that group. If you want to capture more information you need more capture groups.

Comment: Something like https://regex101.com/r/0iyjt8/1

Comment: Wouldn't making the this line a non-capture group give the desired result: `r"\"(?:CONNECT|DELETE|GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|PATCH|POST|PUT|TRACE)\s*"`?

Comment: @Mark I want the HTML request type in the final output so a non-capturing group is not an option.

Comment: @Pioneer_11 did you try it? By adding a non-capturing group you have *no* capture groups, which means you return the whole match. And it's simpler.

Comment: @Mark my mistake, I'm new to regex's and so I assumed a non-capturing group wouldn't capture anything inside it. As you say it works perfectly

Comment: @Mark but if you return the whole match then you still have to extract all the individual fields. Or maybe I've misunderstood "I'm wanting the host, username, time and full request"...

Comment: Slight update to my regex (realised I was capturing the trailing `]` on the time field) https://regex101.com/r/0iyjt8/2

Comment: @Nick agreed, I didn't realise it was possible to match into a tuple so I was trying to match the whole thing as Mark's regex does. However, your solution is far better.